# How do I take the values from two different tables, multiply them together, and aggregate them to a product ID?

Tags: sql

My current code is this, as you can tell this breaks.

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, SUM([Quantity] * [Price]) AS Total_Order_Value 
FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID=Products.ProductID
GROUP BY Products.ProductID
ORDER BY Products.ProductID DESC
```

I have one table (Products) with basic SKU information and (OrderDetails) with just that... order details, quantity, pricing etc.

Both tables have a field called ProductID.

What I want is to merge the tables so I can multiple price by quantity and then spit out a list of all product IDs with their aggregated total spend.

Comment: When you execute that query, what happens? Are you getting an ambiguous column error, of so then you need to specify the table that quantity and price are in.

Comment: Isn't there any order_id?

Comment: @McNets I don't see where that would matter, order_id would likely be the PK of the order table, but since they want the total gross sales by product, all we care about is the quantity per order and the price from that order/

Comment: I'm such a bonehead Andrew, I think I had something hidden in my code and it wasn't working. I reinputted my code above and yielded expected results... sorry.

Comment: I was going to say, that code looked exactly like what I would write to get what you wanted, only I would alias my tables `p` and `o` and have declared the aliases on every column `SELECT p.ProductID, SUM([o.Quantity] * [o.Price])...` just as a matter of good practice habit when dealing with joins (not always required, but always works if there, where it can fail without it)